# Run an external program and extract a pattern match along with the result file

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, bioinformatics, child-process

The script takes two input files of protein sequences and runs an external program (installed in linux/MacOS). The result provides a text output file [example output.](https://pastebin.com/BtT85mGZ). Identity percentage is extracted from the matched keyword "Identity" in the line. Also, the script returns the result text file.

Can you help me to improve this script?

```
import re
import subprocess

def cmdline(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        args=command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True
    )
    return process.communicate()[0]

def blast_two_sequences(file1, file2):

    try:
        # fetch the identity percentage
        #https://www.biostars.org/p/200256/

        cmd = 'needle -datafile EBLOSUM62 -auto Y' + ' -asequence ' + file1 +' -bsequence ' + file2 +  ' -sprotein1 Y -sprotein2 Y ' + ' -auto -stdout'
        # cmd = 'needle -asequence ' + file1 +' -bsequence ' + file2 + ' -auto -stdout'

        results = cmdline(cmd)

        results = results.decode("utf-8")


        identity = re.search(r"\d{1,3}\.\d*\%", results)
        identity = identity.group()
        identity = identity.replace('%', '')

        return identity, results

    except:
        return None


file1 = "/Users/catuf/Desktop/file1.txt"
file2 = "/Users/catuf/Desktop/file2.txt"

if blast_two_sequences(file1, file2) is not None:
    identity, result = blast_two_sequences(file1, file2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not looking bad for as far as I can see. If the example file is accurate for the lengths of the input files, then I don't forsee any real problems, though others may of course disagree.

Naming:

`cmdline` is quite a... short name for a function. I'd think cmd_line for snake_case convention. However, what it does is create what's basically a text file in a bytes buffer by means of running a program. While you could call that a command line execution if you're working from a terminal, I'd name it after the invoked program, or something more generic like `get_input_data`. Since generic is always survivable at best, I'd pick something like `get_needle_results` or something like that.

For a module like subprocess which you can guess does creative things dependent on what platform you're on, it's always advisable to grab the docs:

> *args* should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in *args* if *args* is a sequence. If *args* is a string, the interpretation is platform-dependent and described below. See the *shell* and *executable* arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args as a sequence.

And your platform matters - a lot. If you never switch platform or `needle` implementation, then you can do what you're doing, but if not you're risking a collossal headache with potentially giving it wrong arguments. Therefore, you might want to restructure it to a list of arguments.

And if you don't, use f-strings, the best invention since the list comprehension:

```py
cmd = 'needle -datafile EBLOSUM62 -auto Y' + ' -asequence ' + file1 +' -bsequence ' + file2 +  ' -sprotein1 Y -sprotein2 Y ' + ' -auto -stdout'
# Becomes:
cmd = f'needle -datafile EBLOSUM62 -auto Y -asequence {file1} -bsequence {file2} -sprotein1 Y -sprotein2 Y  -auto -stdout'
```

Which is shorter and more readable.

```py
        results = cmdline(cmd)

        results = results.decode("utf-8")
```

These can be combined:

```py
        results = cmdline(cmd).decode("utf-8")
```

So can these:

```py
        identity = re.search(r"\d{1,3}\.\d*\%", results)
        identity = identity.group()
        identity = identity.replace('%', '')
# New:
        identity = re.search(r"\d{1,3}\.\d*\%", results).group().replace('%', '')
```

```py
if blast_two_sequences(file1, file2) is not None:
    identity, result = blast_two_sequences(file1, file2)
```

And ouch... you're actually running your entire program twice. If your needle executions are counted, you might have noticed this. You should refactor this to:

```py
output = blast_two_sequences(file1, file2)
if output is not None:
    identity, result = output 
# Or if you work with Python 3.8+
if output := blast_two_sequences(file1, file2) is not None:
    identity, result = output
```

You should also put a guard around the actual execution, so that a later scripter can import your functions and use them without executing your script on import:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    file1 = "/Users/catuf/Desktop/file1.txt"
    file2 = "/Users/catuf/Desktop/file2.txt"
    if output := blast_two_sequences(file1, file2) is not None:
        identity, result = output
```

Exceptions:

There's a small issue you have - you have a bare `except` in your code. That means that if weird stuff happens, your program will just ignore it and return none. In your case, I would recommend removing the `try:` statement completely, and you'll be informed about any problems that arise. If you're watching out for specific Exceptions, narrow your `except:` to those, and preferably restrict your try/except to directly around the origin lines of these Exceptions.

This will obsolete your `None` check on the outside. Exceptions showing up on your screen is a good thing - it means you'll be notified when the unexpected happens and you have some unknown error - because now you can go fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much for doing this. It help me a lot.