# Convert text file to html?

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, django, bioinformatics

I have a script that converts a [text file](https://pastebin.com/Bv98Tep3) to html. The text file is an output of a program ([needle](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/psa/emboss_needle/)). The function takes the text file as an input. I am aware the script is awful. I use this function in Django. I would like to improve it. Can you help me with it?. Here is the [result file](https://pastebin.com/1RxEJPfM) from the script.

```
def write_html(result):
    sequence_1 = ''
    sequence_2 = ''
    identity = ''
    similarity = ''
    gaps = ''
    html_string = ''
    with open("/Users/catuf/Desktop/needle_align.txt", "w") as e:
        e.write('{% extends "database/base_table.html" %}' + "\n")
        e.write('\n')
        e.write("{% block content %}"+"\n")
        table1 = '''
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Query Sequence </th>
            <th>Matched Sequence </th>
            <th>Identity </th>
            <th>Similarity </th>
            <th>Gaps </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        '''

        table2 = """
          </tr>
        </table>

        </body>
        </html>
        """
        for line in result.splitlines():
            #s = html.unescape(lines)
            #print(line)
            if line.startswith('# 1:'):
                line = line.split()
                sequence_1 = line[2]
            elif line.startswith('# 2:'):
                line = line.split()
                #print(line)
                sequence_2 = line[2]

            elif line.startswith('# Identity:'):
                identity = re.search(r"\d{1,3}\.\d*\%", line)
                identity = identity.group()
                identity = identity.replace('%', '')
                #identity = float(identity)* 100
                #identity = str(identity)

            elif line.startswith('# Similarity:'):
                similarity = re.search(r"\d{1,3}\.\d*\%", line)
                similarity = similarity.group()
                similarity = similarity.replace('%', '')

            elif line.startswith('# Gaps:'):
                line = line.split()
                gaps = line[2]

            elif line.startswith('#'):
                pass
            else:
                s = "<pre>" + line + "</pre>"
                html_string += s

        e.write(table1)
        e.write("<td>" + sequence_1 + '</td>' + '\n')
        e.write("<td>" + sequence_2 + '</td>'+ '\n')
        e.write("<td>"+ identity + "%" + '</td>'+ '\n')
        e.write("<td>"+ similarity+ "%" +'</td>'+ '\n')
        e.write("<td>"+ gaps+ '</td>'+ '\n')
        e.write(table2)
        e.write(html_string)
        e.write("</head>" + "\n")
        e.write("{% endblock content %}"+"\n")
```

Comment: Could you show us how the output html is rendered?

Comment: Sure I will add rendered one in couple of minutes.

Comment: What he meant is, how and when do you call this function? It is odd that you are programatically creating a template with data in it. There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding here. Anyhow, first thing I'd do is separating the parsing from the rendering.

Comment: As you can see in this [script](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/228866/run-an-external-program-and-extract-a-pattern-match-along-with-the-result-file). I receive the result file as a string from the needle program and call this function.

Answer (score 1):

## Functions

Right now, `write_html` manages both parsing and writing to a file. Separate this function into two functions, perhaps `parse_data` and `write_data`.

## String Formatting

This

```
s = "<pre>" + line + "</pre>"
e.write("<td>" + sequence_1 + '</td>' + '\n')
```

can be written like this

```
s = f"<pre>{line}></pre>"
e.write(f"<td>{sequence_1}</td>\n")
```

The `f""` allows you to directly implement variables into your strings.

## Simplification

This

```
elif line.startswith('# Gaps:'):
    line = line.split()
    gaps = line[2]
```

can be written like this

```
elif line.startswith('# Gaps:'):
    gaps = line.split()[2]
```

The same with these two:

```
if line.startswith('# 1:'):
    sequence_1 = line.split()[2]
elif line.startswith('# 2:'):
    sequence_2 = line.split()[2]
```

## Variable Assignments

This

```
sequence_1 = ''
sequence_2 = ''
identity = ''
similarity = ''
gaps = ''
html_string = ''
```

can be written like this

```
sequence_1, sequence_2, identity, gaps, similarity, html_string = '', '', '', '', '', ''
```

## Type Hints

You can use type hints to make it clear what is being accepted as parameters, and what is being returned by the function.

From this

```
def write_html(result):
```

to this

```
def write_html(result: str) -> None:
```

## Docstrings

You should include a docstring at the beginning of every function, method, class, and module you write. This will allow documentation to identify what these are supposed to do.

```
def write_html(result: str) -> None:
    """
    (Description about this method here)
    """
    ... code here ...
```